# Pass Action Buttons in DataTables using ajax or php

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, datatable, datatables

```
'aoColumns': [
        {'bVisible':true}, // 0 full name
        {'bVisible':false}, // 1 first name
        {'bVisible':false}, // 2 last name
        {'bVisible':false}, // 3 title
        {'bVisible':true}, // 4 company
        {'bVisible':true}, // 5 email
        {'bVisible':true}, // 6 phone
        {'bVisible':false}, // 7 fax
        {'bVisible':false}, // 8 address1
        {'bVisible':false}, // 9 address2
        {'bVisible':false}, // 10 city
        {'bVisible':false}, // 11 state
        {'bVisible':false}, // 12 postal code
        {'bVisible':false}, // 13 country
        {'bVisible':false}, // 14 website
        {'bVisible':false}, // 15 facebook
        {'bVisible':false}, // 16 google+
        {'bVisible':false}, // 17 twitter
        {'bVisible':false}, // 18 linkedin
        {'bVisible':true}, // 19 source
        {'bVisible':true}, // 20 status
        {'bVisible':true}, // 21 type
        {'bVisible':false}, // 22 tags
        {'bVisible':false}, // 23 summary
        {'bVisible':false}, // 24 creation date
        {'bVisible':false}, // 25 last update date -- sort on this column
    ],
```

The above is columns created using ajax/datatables.
Please help me to add Action Buttons like Edit,Show,Delete in this with their respective record id.

Comment: Why don't you try the stwe/DatatablesBundle? https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle